# Want to get a different mapview when a UItableViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, mapkit

As part of my app, one of my tableviews has seven rows/cells. When you click on each of the rows, it will display it's data to a detailed view, changing UILabels with the appropriate data pertaining to this row/cell which was selected. I'm using a mysql database and convert it to json to get the date for the tableview row/cells as well as the detailed view.

In the mysql database, each of the columns which contain a name, street address, longitude and latitude coordinates pertaining to the street addresses.

My tableview as well as my detailed views are populating the correct data. However I'd also like to have subview in my detailed view to contain a mapview, which changes per the street address or the coordinates when the the detailed view shows that particular data.

I can create a mapview/subview in my detailedview.m file as per the code below, but the map stays the same for each row/cell I select. I would like map to have different coordinates per row/cells selected and the data display in the detailed view.

```
//Create NSCC MapView

MKMapView * mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 446, 768, 415)];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 40.494828;
region.center.longitude = -74.443016;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

[mapView setDelegate:self];

//Set PIN Location for NSCC on MKMapView

NSCCDisplayMap *ann = [[NSCCDisplayMap alloc] init];
ann.title = @"NSCC New Brunswick";
ann.subtitle = @"18 Paterson Street New Brunswick, NJ 08901";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];

//Add NSCC MKMapView object as a subview to our view

[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

So I guess my real question is: ???

1. When I select the row/cell in my tableview and it displays the json data from the database correctly in my detailedView for each of the seven rows/cells, how can I get the mapview to change to the appropriate coordinates pertaining to that data displayed in the detailedView?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at these lines of your code -

```
region.center.latitude = 40.494828;
region.center.longitude = -74.443016;
```

then it clearly indicates that you are not using different `latitude` and `longitude` to change the region of `MKMapView`, instead of this you hardcoded some values here.

What you need to do here is when you select a row in `UITableView` then you have to pass coordinates corresponding to that row to your detail view. Then use those coordinates to change the region of `MKMapView`.